# SQL Error code SQL state [S1093]; error code [0];

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am getting the below logs on one of my JSP-Servlet application.

Can anyone explain me what `**SQL state [S1093]; error code [0];**`  means? Or what could be the issue? 
I have already checked the column name `JOB_SYNDICATELOCALE`, it is correct.

```
getSchedulerDetail operation started.
12:50:35,181 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9209-6) Error in getSchedulerDetail() StatementCallback;
 uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM BVTaskSchedulerDetails];
 SQL state [S1093];
 error code [0];
 The column name JOB_SYNDICATELOCALE is not valid.;
 nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name JOB_SYNDICATELOCALE is not valid.
```

Following is the java code, tht calls the query-

```
public List getSchedulerDetail() {
        System.out.println("getSchedulerDetail operation started.");        
        List schedulerDetails = null;
        try {
            String query = getQuery(DynamicSchedulerConstants.SELECT_SCHEDULER_DETAIL);
            schedulerDetails = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new SchedulerDetailsMapper());
        } catch(DataAccessException dae) {
            System.out.println("Error in getSchedulerDetail() " + dae.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("getSchedulerDetail operation complete.");       
        return schedulerDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the Java code which is executing the query?

Comment: public List getSchedulerDetail() {
  System.out.println("getSchedulerDetail operation started.");  
  List schedulerDetails = null;
  try {
   String query = getQuery(DynamicSchedulerConstants.SELECT_SCHEDULER_DETAIL);
   schedulerDetails = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new SchedulerDetailsMapper());
  } catch(DataAccessException dae) {
   System.out.println("Error in getSchedulerDetail() " + dae.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
  System.out.println("getSchedulerDetail operation complete.");  
  return schedulerDetails;
 }

Comment: in the question, formatted.

Comment: What's `DynamicSchedulerConstants.SELECT_SCHEDULER_DETAIL`?

Comment: These Links might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918459/invalid-parameter-number-sql-state-s1093-php-odbc-mssql, https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22962702/Invalid-parameter-number-SQLSTATE-S1093.html

Comment: SELECT_SCHEDULER_DETAIL=SELECT * FROM BVTaskSchedulerDetails